# Trying to show the current log channel for a server discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

Im trying to add something to my help command where it can show the current log channel that is setup for the server. I tried to do it myself from scratch but log_channel is not getting defined. How can I define this? THx

**My def log_channel code:**

```
def get_logchannel(bot, message):
        with open('logchannel.json', 'r') as fp:
          log_channel = json.load(fp)
          return log_channel[str(message.guild.id)]
```

**my help command code:**

```
embed.add_field(name="**Current Log Channel:**", value=f"{log_channel(self.bot, ctx.message)}", inline=False)
```

the `log_channel` in `{log_channel(self.bot, ctx.message)}")` is not getting defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used whats supposedly meant a variable `log_channel` for a function call, which isn't defined anywhere, because your function is called `get_logchannel`.

---

Just replace `log_channel` with the actual function name in your help command and you should be good to go

```
embed.add_field(name="**Current Log Channel:**", value=f"{get_logchannel(self.bot, ctx.message)}", inline=False)
```

Comment: Question, how can I make it where it say something like "no log channel set" if they don't have a log channel setup? If I try to do the help command in a server without a log channel, it does not send the embed.

Comment: In that case `get_logchannel` will throw an `KeyError`. If you catch it, you know that the guild does not have a log-channel set up. I've written a short [code on pastebin](https://pastebin.com/KQcMM1iZ) to demonstrate this.